# Web3js and keccak different values

Tags: solidity, keccak

In solidity there is the keccak256 function which hashes its arguments.
I use the keccak256 to compute and use the result to check if some entries exist in my array.

I want to compute the same value in javascript and check if the entry exists on the blockchain, although the web3.sha gives different value than the keccak256.

How can I compute the same value for the same arguments?

In console I run this:

```
web3.sha3("test1");
```

and my contract:

```
function hashVal(bytes32 val) public returns(bytes32) {
     return keccak256(val);
 }
```

Comment: No one's going to be able to debug your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
web3.sha3(web3.padRight(web3.fromAscii("test1"), 66), { encoding: 'hex' });
```

Explanation:

A `bytes32` representation of "test1" is 32 bytes long, while "test1" is only 5 bytes long.

`web3.fromAscii("test1")` converts the string to its hexadecimal representation with a leading "0x": `0x7465737431`.

`web3.padRight` pads the value with zeros on the right-hand side, like the conversion to `bytes32` does. 32 bytes is 64 hexadecimal characters, but to take into account the leading "0x", I'm padding to 66 characters. This producets `0x7465737431000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, which is a `bytes32` representation of the string.

Finally, we pass this value to `web3.sha3` and specify the `{ encoding: 'hex' }` option so `sha3` interprets the value passed in as hexadecimal rather than ASCII.

Comment: Thanks. What about multiple values? keccak256 supports multiple arguments, how can I do the same with web3.sha3?

Comment: Concatenate, using tightly-packed ABI. See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of this, consider using `soliditySha3` in web3.js or `soliditySHA3` on `ethereumjs-abi`.

Comment: I thought `soliditySha3` is the same but in a different web3 version, no?

Comment: `soliditySha3` takes typed data and encodes it the same way Solidity does so you don't have to do your own ABI-encoding.

Comment: Using `soliditySha3` the hashes are different. How would you do the hash?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: `web3.utils.soliditySha3('test1')` ( --> `0x6d255fc3390ee6b41191da315958b7d6a1e5b17904cc7683558f98acc57977b4`), tried also with `Web3latest.utils.soliditySha3(web3.padRight('test1',66))` (--> `0x31a3b5d3cde7109ca14a8531ac70551e5213183b9c215a6c892927d9bf7d51f3`
but solidity gives `0x14772b6e7a9ffe71c19637eea7a0a6608a98ab5d721db1a4ce039074fab9792a`

Comment: Using web3 1.0.0-beta: `web3.utils.soliditySha3({ type: 'bytes32', value: web3.utils.fromAscii('test1') });`

Comment: that works, thanks! I also wanted to avoid using padRight

Answer (score 1):

If your function is declared as view or pure you can call it from javascript without paying gas, and it should return the exact same result that when it is called from inside the contract

```
function hashVal(string val) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(val);
}
```

And from javascript

```
 var result = await contract.methods.hashVal("hello").call();
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of ensuring that *all client* can easily compute it the way the contract does it, now and *in the future*.