# Different keccak256 for the same string

Tags: solidity, keccak

What is the reason that when i try to get the keccak256 values for the same string (which is "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" or simply value of 1 in bytes32 representation) with web3 and Solidity I get two different values.

1. When I use the following code :

   `await web3.utils.keccak256("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001")`

The output is : `0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6`

2. When I type run the same thing in solidity:

   ```
    function getBytes32() public pure returns (bytes32) 
    {
       return keccak256("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001");
    }
   ```

The output is: `0xcb371be217faa47dab94e0d0ff0840c6cbf41645f0dc1a6ae3f34447155a76f3`

P.S. There is a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42043/web3js-and-keccak-different-values?rq=1) but there the issue was with padding. I have used the exact same string. Both are 32 bytes long (i.e.. 64 chars) and two chars for "0x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first case the output is based on the Hex value, on the second one is based on the string value.

```
return keccak256(abi.encode(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001));
```

it returns the value that you're expecting

```
0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6
```

Comment: This shows an error. Undeclared Identifier error

Comment: @MaksimjeetChowdhary this is another issue, here is the code you can test it on remix it works https://gist.github.com/Aboudjem/7ef81d0c8d44f98e785d34b77da17f4a

Comment: Correct, so as you shared, the following will return the hash the same as web in js:
        bytes32 withString = keccak256(abi.encode("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"));

Closing this.